# Error on Insert Map

Tags: javascript

I am using Drupal 7 and the [Google Map Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_map_field) module. When I click on the *Insert Map* button, the Firebug console shows this:

> TypeError: `$(...).prop` is not a function

It seems like I need `jQuery.noConflict()`, but why is this happening?

Comment: Please mention jquery version used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Drupal ships with jQuery 1.4 and `prop()` was added in 1.6.

You could mess about with a second version of jQuery and `noConflict`, or you can just install the [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module and let it handle things for you.

If that won't work (e.g. it produces other conflicts with existing scripts), try [jQuery Multi](https://www.drupal.org/project/jqmulti) instead.

Comment: It was exactly as you said.
I installed [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) and set up jQuery 1.7 for both, admin and general themes.

Now **Insert map** works without a problem. Thanks @Clive